# Troubleshooting a macOS hard shutdown script with automator

Tags: macos, shutdown, automator, macos-mojave

I am trying to build a script that performs a hard shutdown. The 1 tap equivalent, via touch-bar or keyboard shortcut to holding your power button down. Save nothing, power off.

```
tell application "System Events" to set the visible of every process to true   
set white_list to {"Finder", "Automator"}
try    
    tell application "Finder"    
        set process_list to the name of every process whose visible is true    
    end tell    
    repeat with theProcessName in process_list    
        tell application "System Events"    
            set theId to (unix id of every process whose name is theProcessName)    
            do shell script "kill -9 " & theId    
        end tell    
    end repeat    
    tell application "System Events" to shut down    
on error    
    tell the current application to display dialog "An error has occurred!" & return & "This script will now quit" buttons {"Quit"} default button 1 with icon 0    
end try
```

This is what I've got so far; it almost always results in an error.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The script fails because the line

```
set theId to (unix id of every process whose name is theProcessName)
```

returns a list (multiple items). Replace it with

```
set theId to unix id of process theProcessName
```

The `whose` clause is redundant as you already got the proper process name.

Note:

For debugging purpose it's highly recommended to print the error

```
on error e   
    tell the current application to display dialog "The error '" & e & "' has occurred!" & return & "This script will now quit" buttons {"Quit"} default button 1 with icon 0    
end try
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! -- It works with keyboard shortcuts, using the touchbar it complains about apple script's changing system events for some reason; but the keyboard is good enough.